# Sync Data From Many Clients to Server (SQL)

Tags: asp.net, sql, wcf, synchronization

My sync functionality needs to sync data from multiple client SQL servers, modify the data based on business rules on the server, and then load the data into the server SQL database.

My current solution is a console application running as a scheduled task, it compares the created and modified time stamps of the records and generates entity objects that either need to be updated or inserted from the client to the server.

While this approach seems to work i'm concerned about conflict management, or disruptions in the WCF services during the sync which would cause data conflicts. One of the thoughts I had to combat this was snapshot then basing sync off that snapshot, if sync completes delete the snapshot and update the Server DB with the last successful import date.

I have looked into Sync Framework, but have found few examples of multiple clients to one server setup. Another issue with sync is that i would prefer not to alter any of the client DB table schema. Are there any examples of read-only from a client DB? Or SQL-SQL examples while modifying the data either on the client or server end?

For reference here is the client code i am using to generate a list of entity objects that need to be updated or inserted into my server database.

```
 Public Function GetNew(ByVal StarTime As DateTime, ByVal EndTime As DateTime, ByVal ChunkSize As Integer, ByVal Offset As Integer) As List(Of myEntity.person) Implements myWCFService.GetNew
    Dim db As New myEntity.DBContext
    Dim z As List(Of INextGen.person) = (From p In db.people Where p.create_timestamp >= StarTime And p.create_timestamp <= EndTime Order By p.create_timestamp Descending Skip Offset Take ChunkSize).ToList()
    Return z
    db.Dispose()
    db = Nothing
End Function

Public Function GetChanged(ByVal StarTime As DateTime, ByVal EndTime As DateTime, ByVal ChunkSize As Integer, ByVal Offset As Integer) As List(Of myEntity.person) Implements myWCFService.GetChanged
    Dim db As New myEntity.DBContext
    Dim z As List(Of INextGen.person) = (From p In db.people Order By p.modify_timestamp >= StarTime And p.modify_timestamp <= EndTime Order By p.modify_timestamp Descending Skip Offset Take ChunkSize).ToList()
    Return z
    db.Dispose()
    db = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1.

Database synchronization providers are a part of the Microsoft® Sync Framework. Sync Framework is a comprehensive synchronization platform that enables developers to add synchronization capabilities to applications, services, and devices. Sync Framework solves the problem of how to synchronize any type of data in any store using any protocol over any topology. Fundamental to Sync Framework is the ability to support offline and collaboration of data between any types of endpoints (such as device to desktop, device to server, etc.).

References:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902831.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726002.aspx

Comment: I looked into that, this is not a true sync in such a way that i need to massage the data coming out of the client SQL before it is inserted into my server SQL. It seems like it is not the right tool for what I am looking to do?

Comment: For what it’s worth, the Sync Framework includes managed and unmanaged APIs for building various custom providers that enable greater synchronization control within the framework.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902847.aspx.  Best Regards.

Comment: One of the needs of the application is a 1 Server, Many client relationship. Such that I could have 3 Client databases and each contains a "Person" table, which i need to sync with my Server table. To keep track of the records i assign a client ID using my WCF model. It seems like Sync does not have much support for this? An additional constraint is i only have read-only access on the client tables.